# OpenVPN plus SQUID

Tags: openvpn, squid

Diagram:

```
OpenVPN client A ----> openVPN Server A ----> Squid Proxy (remote)
```

When client A connects to openVPN Server A, I want all of his traffic going to the squid proxy and exiting through that WAN interface on Squid (remote location).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting up iptables to forward traffic to the squid box:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html

Google for 'transparent proxy squid' if you need more examples.